# using psql, can I override variables set in .psqlrc from command line?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I would like to have a `.psqlrc` file with default values, and be able to override these values from `psql`'s command line.

For example :

- have some values set in `.psqlrc` :

```
-- .psqlrc :
-- "user@database # " in bold green
\set PROMPT1 '%[%033[1;32;40m%]%n@%/%[%033[0m%]% > '
-- store command history in home directory, with a per database file :
\set HISTFILE ~/.psql-history- :DBNAME
```

- in some wrapper script `master-psql.sh`, which connects as user `postgres`, be able to override these values :

```sh
# master-psql.sh :
# when using this script, change color to red, change history file location :
psql -U postgres \
  -v PROMPT1='%[%033[1;31;40m%]%n@%/%[%033[0m%]% # ' \
  -v HISTFILE='/some/other/place/.psql_history_postgres'
```

The above does not work, because the the `-v ...` argument is executed *before* the `.psqlrc` file is loaded, and the instruction in `.psqlrc` overwrites the existing value.

**Question**

Is there a way to instruct `psql` to run a set of commands *after* loading its `.psqlrc` file(s),
or to have `.psqlrc` execute some `\set` or `\pset` command only if value is not set ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html

> **Environment**
> [...]
>
> **PSQLRC**
> Alternative location of the user's .psqlrc file. Tilde (~) expansion is performed.

So create an alternate `.psqlrc` file and set the`PSQLRC` environment variable for the script to override your default.

Comment: I have been testing @jjanes suggestion, but coding too much stuff using psql syntax seems brittle, and I couldn't convince myself I wasn't inadvertently adding bugs. This solution is safer.

Comment: To complete this answer : `psql` has an `\ir or \include_relative filename` metacommand, so I can write `\ir .psqlrc` in my `.psqlrc-master` file to get all my "default" values, and override the values I want.

Answer (score 3):

You could write the instructions not to overwrite those variables if already set into the `.psqlrc` file itself:

```
\if :{?HISTFILE}
\else
\set HISTFILE ~/.psql-history- :DBNAME
\endif
```

If you can't get your system psqlrc to cooperate with you, then might need to copy and modify it and then bypass the original.  You need at least v11 for the `:{?` construct to work.

The problem is that PROMPT1 has a compiled-in default even in the absence of RC file processing, so you might need to test that against the compiled-in string, rather than test for being defined.  So I think that would end up with something like this:

```
select :'PROMPT1'='%/%R%x%# ' as default_prompt \gset
\if :default_prompt
\set PROMPT1 '%[%033[1;32;40m%]%n@%/%[%033[0m%]% > '
\endif
```

Note that the compiled in default changed in v13, so if you want to work with older versions as well, you would need to do something more complicated.

Comment: Nice, I was cooking something looking like that. Is `SELECT :'PROMPT1' = ...`  safe against sql injections ? (through the values of `PROMPT1`)

Comment: That is the purpose of `:''`, so it should be safe.  I'd certainly try out a few things before blindly letting strangers set my PROMPT1, though.